# jQuery post not triggering PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to trigger a PHP script using `post` when a user clicks a button, but nothing happens. I tested to check if the correct button is clicked using `alert` and it is clicked, but after that nothing happens. This is the code:

html file:

```
<body>
<input type="submit" class="button" id="' . $row['id'] . '" value="submit">
       
<script src="/js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/update.js"></script>
</body>
```

`update.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".button", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id); // the correct id shows up

        $.post("/test_folder/test_post.php") // send to simple php test script
                .done(function () {
                    alert("done");
        });
```

`test_post.php` file:

```
<?php
echo "Test";
exit;
```

Comment: So did you check for errors in the browser's console and network tools?

Comment: Haha yes, thank you I now checked and saw it: I am using the slim version of jQuery and I needed the non-slim one. works now (The slim version doesn't include ajax functions)